# Memory Error: Jupyter Notebook restricted to 32-bit

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

I am working in a Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to run the following line of code:

t = np.linspace(1, 6469693230 , 6469693230 )

However, I receive a memory error.

Obviously, np.linspace was working fine with smaller numbers. This was the first number that gave me problems. Notcie that this number is 32-bit, whereas all the previous numbers I had used were less than 32-bit.

When I open python console, it reads:

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Which is strange since my computer is Windows 64-bit.

Also, when I write:

import platform

print(platform.architecture())

It prints:
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

I am pretty new to this stuff, so I'm not too sure what other information I should provide. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have at least `(4 * 6469693230) / 1_000_000_000 == 25.87877292` _gigabytes_ of RAM? I'm also pretty sure that your floating-point numbers are _8 bytes long_ so you'll need around 52 gigs.

Comment: @ForceBru, would you mind explaining that calculation? Also, is there any specific reason why my floating-point numbers are 8 bytes long? Is there any way to alleviate this?

Comment: The third argument of `linspace` is the number of entries to generate, so your call will attempt to generate 6469693230 floating-point numbers. Since you're using a 64-bit machine, your floating-point numbers will most likely be `double`s, or, as per the IEEE standard, `binary64`s, which are 64 bits (8 bytes) long. I think you can choose a different datatype, like `numpy.float32` or something, but it won't help much since you'll still need more than 25 gigs of RAM.